# how to fetch values from special attribute names with LINQ and XML

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

XML is like this:

```
<element customer-name="blabla" customer-identifier="blabla2">
```

and I'm using VB.net, doing something like this:

```
name = xmlstring.<element>.@customer-name
```

This doesnt work, because you cannot enter "@customer-name" in the LINQ query. Is there way to escape minus sign becoming an operator?

Answer (score 1):

Use angle brackets to escape the name:

```
Dim xmlstring = <element customer-name="blabla" customer-identifier="blabla2"/>
Dim name = xmlstring.@<customer-name>
```